# Facebook SSO returns when app is killed

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

I use facebook for android sdk for SSO.

My activity calls `fb.authorize()` function to do OAuth. In this function I give a reference to the `DialogListener` object that is responsible to take proper actions depending on OAuth results. It is possible that the OS has killed the activity by the time user returns from FB App and the DialogListener Object is lost. In that case there's no way to get the AccessTokens which we were supposed to get in DialogListener.

How to handle this situation?

Comment: It depends on why it is crashing. Do you have a stacktrace?

Comment: It is crashing because of null pointer exception. In some function other than `onCreate()` I use `mFB = new Facebook(APPID);` and in `onActivityResult` I call `mFB.authorizeCallback(bundle);`. and `mFB` is my class variable. Since it is not initiated in `onCreate` it returns me a null pointer exception. I can completely avoid it from crashing. But since attached dialog listener is now gone with activity being killed, how can i get the access tokens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am answering this myself.

Facebook app after doing OAuth returns results in an intent data which we get in `onActivityResult();` It is required to call `mFB.authorizeCallback()` in `onActivityResult`.

If you look into the source of this function, you will know how to extract it from the intent data. And doing that you can get access tokens in onActivityResult.

Here's the link to the source 
https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/master/facebook/src/com/facebook/android/Facebook.java#L417

Answer (score 0):

You can call:

```
mFB.getAccessToken()
```

But you can store the session in SharedPreferences to reuse it locally. Tokens will expire and will be requested and stored when needed again.

https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/master/examples/simple/src/com/facebook/android/SessionStore.java